# FragmentTransaction .attach and .detach for Actionbar tabs

Tags: android, transactions, fragment, detach

I'm trying to get the code [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html) to work.  It compiles fine.  It will run.  And it will load tab 1 (of 3).  However, when I click on the 2nd or 3rd tab, I get this:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.FragmentTransaction.detach

this happens in the code here

```
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment != null) {
        //ft.detach(mFragment); //requires API Level 13
        ft.remove(mFragment); //this does not do the same thing as detach
    }
}
```

I found that [detach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29) is only available to API Level 13.  I tried [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29), but it doesn't do the same thing, obviously. Does anyone have any ideas about how to overcome this based on the code in the first [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html)?

---

EDIT:
I guess the same goes for [attach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach%28android.app.Fragment%29) as that's also in the code, but doesn't get hit before the app crashes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that replacing the several places in the code that reference attach and detach with add and remove will allow the code to function normally in a pre-API Level 13 environment.

```
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null) { // && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.remove(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        //} else {
        //    ft.attach(mFragment);
        //}
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            //ft.detach(mFragment); //requires API 13
            ft.remove(mFragment); //this does not do the same thing as detach
        }
    }
```

Comment: but with ft.add/remove fragment state is lost when switching between tabs

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the FragmentTransaction in API 4+ compatablity package -android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction -  you should be able to call attach and detach methods on pre API level 13 platforms.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html

Comment: Related blog post: [Fragments for all](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

Answer (score 1):

or just use http://actionbarsherlock.com/
you will have consistent action bar experience from 2.x up