# ActionBar List Navigation Overlapping Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement the Android Action Bar in list navigation mode, it successfully changes fragments when an item is selected from the list, but the fragments overlap and I can see the content of the previous one still on the screen when the second is selected. Here's my code for the Activity's OnCreate and OnNavigationItemSelected:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFirstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    mSecondFragment = new SecondFragment();

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, 
            R.array.action_list, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt("currFragment"));
    }
}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch(position) {
        case FIRST_FRAGMENT:
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(
                    android.R.id.content, 
                    mFirstFragment);
            break;
        case SECOND_FRAGMENT:
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(
                    android.R.id.content, 
                    mSecondFragment);
            break;
    }
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();

    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. The accepted answer in [FragmentTransaction .attach and .detach for Actionbar tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025449/fragmenttransaction-attach-and-detach-for-actionbar-tabs) worked for me. You may also get good pointers from [Android Action Bar Tab with scrollview made duplicate view after orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885594/android-action-bar-tab-with-scrollview-made-duplicate-view-after-orientation-cha) ( although the key insights that worked for me came from the first question that I have linked to ).